# Communication between two separated views in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have *`MainWindows.xaml`* containing two Controls elements. First is connected with `MapView.xaml`  *`<Controls:MapView />`* and second with `InfoView.xaml` *`<Controls:InfoView />`*. Now I want to execute method from `InfoView dataContext` object *`InfoViewModel`* from *`MapView DataContext`* Object *`MapViewModel`*.

How can I do this?

MapView.xaml.cs

```
public MapView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _mapViewModel = new MapViewModel();
        this.DataContext = _mapViewModel;
    }
```

InfoView.xaml.cs

```
public InfoView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _infoViewModel = new InfoViewModel();
        this.DataContext = _infoViewModel;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of approacges is to use the EventAggregator and your own event to send the notification from the source and catch it in the subscriber.

An advantage of this approach is that is it generic, you can send any messages from anywhere to anywhere to accomplish anything, you send the message from the source and catch it in the subscriber.

The EventAggregator is built into Prism.